# Getting wrong values in fs->win array after sending CMD17 command on sd card in check_fs function

Tags: embedded

In check_fs function when I read the data of sector 0 which provides the information regarding sd card the values I get in the fs->win array are different.

I checked the micro sd card in disk investigator it is showing proper data in it.

```
if (LD_WORD(&fs->win[BS_55AA]) != 0xAA55)- this condition gets true as i get the 55aa at fs->win[510]
```

but for condition -> `if ((DWORD)(*(DWORD*)(&fs->win[BS_FilSysType]) & 0xFFFFFF) == 0x544146)`
is not getting true as i am not getting value 554146 at desired location of fs->win[54]

and code is going in hardfault.

is there any issue with clock frequency?
what is exact clock rate required to read the data from card?

my spi is working fine, getting proper response to all commands.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/likGe.jpg)

below are the value i am getting in win[]

Comment: What value *are* you getting instead? Could be a byte order issue.

Comment: at location win[54],win[55],win[56] values should be 46,41 and 55 respectively, but instead i am getting 0x00, 0x55, 0xc6. what is the byte order issue? how it occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: This is obviously the Chan VFAT code - Your changed bytes don't look like a byte order issue - Are you sure you are placing received bytes in the win buffer without an offset?

Comment: You should be showing your `disk_read` function. The problem seems to be there.

Comment: i am getting the following message in win buffer "invalid partition table.Error loading operating system. Missing operating system." what dose that mean?

Comment: This looks like a Windows 7 MBR, then. I think you are reading the card in the wrong place.

Comment: what shoud i do then

Comment: Create a dump of the first few sectors. Locate from *where you read* and compare to from *where you want to read* - Determine the offset, find in your code where it's introduced.

Comment: when i check the sd card in disk investigation utility it showing correct data in sector 0

Comment: i have tried reading other sectors also but getting zero's only...

Comment: In case your card really has an MBR, you seem to be reading the proper sector - but with an offset to it. Do as in my above comment

Comment: currently i am reading the sector which starts from 0x00, then how can i get the offset if location i want to read also starts from the 0x00

Comment: Repeating my above comment is boring, but probably inevitable: *Create a dump of the first few sectors. Locate from where you read and compare to from where you want to read - Determine the offset, find in your code where it's introduced*

Comment: how to create the dump? i am confused about it.